# Save my file on a shared drive google colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

We are working as a team on a Shared Drive, we are using Google Colab to support our code.

Here is the path : /content/drive/Shared drives/Projet_IE/Technique/BDD

We want to save the file (.json) in our drive, but it fails because of the blank in the "Shared drives"

How can we make this path understandable by the code, since "Shared drives" is impose by GDrive and the code doesn't understand the blank in the path ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.colab import drive
import json
!mkdir -p /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/test
a = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
with open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/test/your_json_file", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(a , fp)
```

Comment: This is code for Google Colab it will save json file into they Gdrive.